# Cannot ping GW using static IP in a specific subnet, but can ping it using another subnet

Tags: networking

I just ran against a strange problem a few weeks ago, and I'm still scraching my head about it.

We have an auth server (WServ 2016) running ADDS/ADFS/DNS/DHCP, having 172.17.0.5/24 as static IP and GW set to 172.17.0.1.
The 172.17.0.5/24 subnet is dedicated to common services used by each subnet.

There are other subnets, such as 172.17.1.0/24 (managed services), 172.17.127.0/24 (storage ressources) and 172.17.128.0/20 (hosting ressources).

A pfSense router/FW makes the job for inter-subnet communication and Internet access (there are virtual IPs on the LAN NIC).

I had to reboot the auth server a few hours ago, and it won't go back online.
I cannot ping the GW using the 172.17.0.5/24 IP, or using any IP in the 172.17.0.0/24 subnet. But if I set the static IP to 172.17.1.19/24 i.e., I can ping everything and access the Internet.

There is no FW rule blocking the communication between subnets, since this a pre-prod network.

I suspected an equipment already using the 172.17.0.5 IP, but since the whole subnet appears to be blocked, I don't know what to check.

Any idea about this?

Comment: Server just went back online, but after 1 hour... is there any troubleshooting step I can do?

Comment: Please update your question and provide more detail. You can your RCA inspecting the logs for warning or errors, please share the logs.

Comment: @ArdenSmith what is a RCA?
And I don't know what to check for logs, the pfSense maybe?

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot ping the GW using the 172.17.0.5/24 IP, or using any IP in the 172.17.0.0/24 subnet. But if I set the static IP to 172.17.1.19/24 i.e., I can ping everything and access the Internet.

Apparently, that server has moved to a different VLAN (assuming your subnets are separated into VLANs). Check switch configs and cabling.

Comment: I do not have any VLAN configured on my pfSense. The switches used are non-manageable (cost reduction...).
So the subnets are separated by using pfSense's virtual IPs as gateways on a single physical NIC, and the subnets are cabled through a few switches going on a single on to this NIC.

Comment: Where's the sense in using multiple IP subnets without VLANs? One of the other possibilities is a MAC-IP binding/static ARP entry on the pfSense - but without a proper description of your network we could guess for ages (which is off-topic here btw).

Comment: These are pre-prod network for a really small client we have, and they reported us this problem.
I can make a scheme and add it to my description tomorrow.